# Could we use spin in transistors?

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, semiconductor-physics, electronics

can we make a transistor which uses magnetic field? the idea is to put a magnetic material between two magnetic materials which have a fixed magnetization direction. We give the middle material a magnetic field that will be magnetized  in opposite direction to the other two materials. so when current pass through  one of the materials it will be polarized in a direction that repels with the middle magnetic material . this repulsion between the electrons and magnetic material will make current stop by overcoming electricity using magnetic force.

Comment: You mean spintronics?

Comment: yes I mean spintronics